# Referencing foreign keys with DataMapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datamapper

I've been looking through this:

http://datamapper.org/docs/find

But haven't been able to gleam what I'm looking for, though I know it's quite simple.

I have two tables, scans and stations, with the relevant fields:

```
STATIONS - id (primary key), name
SCANS    - id (primary key), item_id, in_station, out_station
```

Where `in_station` and `out_station` are foreign keys to the `id` field in the `stations` table.

I have a `Scan` object

```
class Scan
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id,                       Integer, :key => true
    property :item_id,                  Integer
    property :in_station,               Integer
    property :out_station,              Integer
end
```

So right now, I can do `Scan.all(:item_id => @barcode)` to get all the scans on a particular item, and I've got the `in_station` id and `out_station` id. What's the best way of getting the *names*, though, instead of ids. I assume it's gotta be easier than for every scan calling `Station.get(:id=> scan.in_station)`.

This is easy enough using SQL, but how can I alter Scan/Station to either get the name or have a property that's a Station object, so I can do something like scan.station.name?

***EDIT:***

I've almost got this working. I have a Station class:

```
class Station
    include DataMapper::Resource

    property :id, Integer, :key => true
    property :name, String
end
```

and I got rid of `property :in_station` and `property :out_station` in `Scan` and replaced with:

```
belongs_to :in_station,        :model => 'Station', :child_key => 'id'
belongs_to :out_station,       :model => 'Station', :child_key => 'id'
```

Which I think/hope is saying "there's a field called in_station which is a foreign key into the Station table and one called out_station which is the same". Indeed, in_station and out_station are now instances of Station, BUT, they're the object. Even though in_station and out_station are different values, I'm getting the same object for each on every Scan. What am I doing wrong, how can I indicate that in_station and out_station are both references to Station but, when their ids are different, I expect different objects.

Comment: Look at the fields that were created in the database for Scan table.  Like I said below, although the name 'child_key' suggests otherwise, you need to use names like I illustrate below.

What your `belongs_to` lines say is "Scan belongs to a Station with an association named 'in_station' and will load the Station with an `id` that matches the Scan property named `id`."  That's not what you want.  You want "Scan belongs to a Station with an association named 'in_station' and will load the Station with an `id` that matches the Scan property named `in_station_id`."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is that we don't want to change the underlying SQL schema.  So we have to tell DataMapper to use the existing foreign key names (in_station and out_station).  The twist is that DataMapper will choke if the association name is the same as the child key.  That's why I have the 'my_' prefix on the association names.

```
class Scan
  include DataMapper::Resource

  #rest of the properties

  belongs_to :my_in_station, :model => 'Station', :child_key => 'in_station'
  belongs_to :my_out_station, :model => 'Station', :child_key => 'out_station'
end
```

Usage

```
s = Scan.get(id)
s.my_in_station.name
s.my_out_station.name
```

Comment: Alright, excuse my ignorance, but once I've done this (I changed the :child_keys to be just 'id', as that is the field name in Station, or should it be reversed), how can I access the name?

I have a bunch of Scan objects, and I want the name of the station they were scanned in on and the name they were scanned out from.

Comment: Don't change the :child_key.  DataMapper already knows that the key of the 'Station' model is 'id'.  I'll add a usage example.

Comment: If I change the :child_key's to anything _but_ id I get an error - either Stack Level too deep or unknown column 'in_station_id' in field list.

Comment: Think of `:child_key` as the foreign key.  So you use it to say "Add a foreign key with this name to the current model."

Comment: What migrations are those? The model given matches the mysql backend. There is no key called 'in_station_id' anywhere in the table, there is just in_station and out_station in the scans table, both of which reference the field simply called "id" in the stations table. If I put the child_key as 'in_station' and 'out_station' I get an error:

stack level too deep

    * file: many_to_one.rb
    * location: target_key
    * line: 271

if I put them both to id, I get a Station object, but the same for both in and out_station even though different station ids are indicated in the DB.

Comment: You are on the right track by changing the :child_key value to 'in_station' (if you don't want to change the mysql schema). Try renaming the associations so that you have `belongs_to :my_in_station, :model => 'Station', :child_key -> 'in_station'`.

Comment: Ah, yes, beautiful, that was it, changing the first parameter in :belongs_to to be something new and the :child_key to be the field as it's called in the scans table (e.g. in_staion and out_station). Now, that first parameter is a Station object (and appears to be correct) and in_station and out_station remain ids. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

How about doing this:

```
class Station
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  # rest of the properties

  has n, :scans
end

class Scan
  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id, Serial
  # rest of the properties

  belongs_to :station
end
```

Then you just do this to access the associated station:

```
station = Station.create
scan    = station.scans.create

scan.station # returns the associated station
```

That should work for you at match your schema.

Comment: I just updated the question, there was lack of clarity. in_station and out_station and ids and reference the id in the stations table/model.

I'd like to be able to do `Scan.all(:item_id => @barcode)` to get all the scans on a particular item, and then go through those scans and get the names of where they were scanned in and out. Right now I can get the id of where it's scanned in and out, I'd just like the name instead, and id is a foreign key to the stations table which has a name. How can I tell DataMapper that in_station and out_station are stations?